# How to use pretty date in jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Am getting pretty date not defined error.Please help me with this.

```
"columnDefs": [{
                  "targets" : 3,
                  "render" : function(data,type,row){
                     return prettyDate(new Date(data.Date))
                 } 
              }],
```

Comment: Where is `prettyDate()` defined?

Comment: actually i added prettydate.js in my jsp